# Unity Searchable Dropdown

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, search, dropdown

Hello everyone I am trying to make a Searchable Dropdown with TMPro InputField. It currently gets the first letter but I couldn't figure out how to add the other letters. For example if I write "a" in input field it gets me the options that start with the letter "a" but if I wrote "an" nothing changes.

```
 private void Start()
    {
        UpdateEmoteDropdown();

    }

    public void UpdateEmoteDropdown()
    {

        CurrentText = InputField.text;

        emoteDropdown.options.Clear();

        emoteDropdown.value = 0;

        foreach (var animation in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Animations)))
        {
            string name = Enum.GetName(typeof(Animations), animation);

            if (CurrentText.Length == 0)
            {
                emoteDropdown.options.Add(new Dropdown.OptionData()
                {
                    text = name
                });

            }
            else {
                if (CurrentText[0] == name[0])
                {
                    emoteDropdown.options.Add(new Dropdown.OptionData()
                    {
                        text = name
                    });
                }
            }

        }

        emoteDropdown.RefreshShownValue();

        emoteDropdown.value = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you only ever check the very first letter in

```
if(CurrentText[0] == name[0])
```

what about rather using e.g. [`string.StartsWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith)

```
if(name.StartsWith(CurrentText))
```

or if you even want to include results that contain the given string at any point not just the beginning rather use [`string.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.contains)

```
if(name.Contains(CurrentText))
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the advice! I coulnd't write the algorithm thats why I am only checking the first letter. I want it to check everytime I type how can I do that ?

Comment: I tried `if(name.StartsWith(CurrentText))` this and it worked thanks a lot !

Comment: When I type something that is not in my dropdown values I get this error. Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. How can I fix that ?